ADFS as SAML IDP in Okta
I have installed and configure ADFS on windows server 2019 (VM). Added Okta SAML IDP details in my relying party trust using metadata url. Signature is configured correctly on both sides as i have use same on and added that to trusted root securities. What i am unable to understand is when i am using this relying party i am not able to sign in even though response returned from Okta is 200 but error message pops up for access denied. Their is nothing in ADFS event logs
Before this their was error related to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier
which i resolved by moving certificate from personal to trusted security.
